# Conditional PMF

Tags: probability

If I have a set $U$ with the numbers $0-9$ (so $|U| = 10$) and I let $A$ be a chosen number and $B$ also be a chosen number after $A$ is chosen and removed from $U$, then I want to know what the conditional PMF that $A = a$.

The way I'm currently thinking about this is as follows:

$P(B \mid A = a) = \frac19 \cdot i$ where $0 \leq i \leq 9$ with $i$ not equal to $a$

My explanation is that the probability of choosing any of the remaining $9$ numbers is $\frac19$, and there are numbers $0$ to $9$ without the number $a$.

Comment: edited my question, sorry about the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the removal process is **uniformly distributed** over that discrete interval, then:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(A=a) & = \frac 1{10} & \text{for }a\in\{0..,9\}
\\[2ex]
\Pr(B=b\mid A=a) & = \frac 1 9 & \text{for }a\in\{0..,9\}\wedge b\in\{0..,9\}\setminus\{a\} 
\\[2ex]
\Pr(B=b) & = \sum_{a\in\{0..,9\}\setminus\{b\}} \Pr(A=a)\Pr(B=b\mid A=a) & \text{for } b\in \{0..,9\}
\\[1ex]
& = 9\cdot \frac 1{10}\cdot\frac 1 9
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 {10}
\end{align}$$

> My explanation is that the probability of choosing any of the remaining 9  numbers is $1\over 9$  , and there are numbers 0  to 9  without the number a .

You are looking for the *conditional probability mass function* of $B=b$ given $A=a$.  What you had was *almost* the *conditional cumulative distribution function* of $B\leq b$ given $A=a$.
$$\Pr(B\leq b\mid A=a) = \begin{cases} \frac b 9 & a\in\{1..,9\}, b\in\{0..,a-1\} \\ \frac {b-1}9 & a\in\{0..,9\}, b\in\{a+1.., 8\} \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$